# GS option in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[3];
    cout<<"before"<<endl;
    strcpy(buf,argv[1]);
    cout<<"after"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My argument is "123456" and I get error overflow. 
When I use /GS on and /GS off there is not any different in work. 
Why? I always print before, after and get error. 
I thought that  the return  address rewrittens. But how can I check it?

Comment: How would 7 characters fit in an array of size 3: `char buf[3];`??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: _"When I use /GS on and /GS off there is not any different in work. Why?"_ How would you expect a difference should be?

Comment: I dont know. Can I see the  different?

Answer (score 0):

The `/GS` switch only inserts checks into function that it ["**recognizes as subject to buffer overrun problems**"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c.aspx). in particular:

> A buffer overrun security check is performed on a **GS buffer**. A GS
>   buffer can be one of these:
>
> - An array that is larger than 4 bytes, has more than two elements, and    has an element type that is not a pointer type.
> - A data structure  whose size is more than 8 bytes and contains no pointers.
> - A buffer allocated by using the `_alloca function.
> - Any class or structure that    contains a GS buffer.

Since your buffer is less than 4 bytes, it's not considered as a GS buffer and so the check is not inserted.

However, even if you increase the buffer size and trigger the overflow, you won't see a difference, because the check is done only *when `main` returns*, i.e. after both messages have been printed. To test that it works, move the buffer and strcpy into a separate function - you'll see that the program exits before returning from it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int setarg(char * arg)
{
 char buf[5];
 strcpy(buf,arg);
 return buf[0];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
cout<<"before"<<endl;
if ( argc >1 )
  setarg(argv[1]);
cout<<"after"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```